# Latest podcast doesn't show commentary

Tags: bug, blog

> We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our
>   troubleshooting guide.

That is what is found on the bottom of the latest so podcast.

Comment: Do you have a link to exactly where you're seeing this?

Comment: @MarcGravell http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/Stack-Overflow-Podcast-93-A-Very-Spolsky-Halloween-Special/ Others podcasts/blog entries don't have this problem.